# If I upgrade macOS from 10.15.6 to latest beta version of MAC 11 Big Sur, will all settings persist after upgrade

Tags: macos, mac, operating-systems, macos-catalina

I have macOS 10.15.6, would like to upgrade to new macOS beta version MAC 11 Big Sur

I have some important data and applications that I can't uninstall

so, will all setting persist after upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

All anyone can say is "probably".
It's a beta, things can go wrong, or not work as expected. You are installing it to **test** if it works for you.

Rules for beta testing.

1. Never use a mission-critical machine.
   Subordinate to this is; never switch OS or software in the middle of a critical mission, unless it is specifically to test compatibility.
2. Never install a beta without a tested return path to non-beta status.
   This would be at minimum a Time Machine backup, which you remove from the system **before** updating [otherwise you can't get back] but preferably also an entire clone.